# Configure nat on src ip to dst port

Tags: nat

I wondering about some workaround for issue that I have: I have 2 sources which generates multicast to 224.1.1.1 and port 12345. I'd like to configure on my Cisco IE 3000 NAT which will change the destination port based on source IP.

Is it possible, how can I do that (i.e. what it the command)?

Comment: That is a reserved multicast group that should not be used. IANA says, "_No new assignments are being made in this range for the time being._" You are free to use multicast froups in the Organization-Local scope: `239.0.0.0/8`.

Comment: the 224.1.1.1 is just an example. it could be 230.1.1.1

Comment: That is also in a reserved range. We need real information, and your router configuration. How is your multicast routing configured? You should include the router configuration in your question.

Comment: flat network - no VLANs

Comment: NAT runs on a layer-3 device, like a router. On a single network, frames are delivered directly from host-to-host, and you have no way to change layer-3 or layer-4.

Comment: As far as I know, IE 3000 has L3 capabilities

Comment: Right, but on the same network, frames are delivered directly from host-to-host. Switches, even layer-3 switches, do not NAT, and to NAT, you would need to send packets between networks, not on the same network.

Comment: NAT is a L3 function.  So unless you are routing from one VLAN to another, you can't do NAT.

Comment: This could be arranged.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the IE3000's capabilities.  However, **source NAT** might be able to do what you want.  I suggest you experiment as this is quite a corner-case.  It may be worth mentioning that *a PC proxying the traffic at layer-4 might be easier* depending on if that is practical in your environment.